# Dynamic C, How to add 2 "hours" as 4 digit Integer

Tags: c, dynamic, time, integer, addition

I need to know how can I add 2 "hours" as integer?
It is 24-h format

```
int add2Hours(int _time1,int _time2)
{ 
}
```

sample: 13:45 is: (hhmm) 1345

1345 + 30 returns 1415

Comment: Best would be change your time representation to seconds. Then you can just use `+`. Why are you using this strange representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys... here is my function!

```
int Add2Times (int _time1, int _time2)
{
    int hour = _time1 / 100 + _time2 / 100;
    int min = _time1 % 100 + _time2 % 100;

    hour += min / 60;
    min = min % 60;


    hour = hour % 24;

    return hour * 100 + min;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your time is in `hhmm` format, separate the `hh` and `mm` part. Then add the parts separately.

```
int add2hours(int _time1, int _time2)
{
    int hh1, hh2, mm1, mm2;
    int rHH,rMM, res;
    hh1 = _time1/100;
    hh2 = _time2/100;
    mm1 = _time1 % 100;
    mm2 = _time2 % 100;
    rMM = mm1 + mm2;
    rHH = rMM/60;
    rMM = rMM % 60;
    rHH = rHH + hh1 + hh2;
    res = rHH*100 + rMM;
    return res;
}
```

**NOTE:** *This will not handle any time greater than 24hrs. e.g. if the inputs are 2345 and 30, the output will be 2415 instead of 15(0015). You have to handle it if you need.*

Answer (score 2):

If the function for adding time is declared as follows,

```
int add2Hours(int _time1,int _time2);
```

and the syntax of passing time is as follows,

```
hhmm (For example 2230)
```

Then you can add the times as follow,

```
temp1= _time1;
temp2= _time2;

m1 = temp1 % 100;
m2 = temp2 % 100;

h1 = temp1 / 100;
h2 = temp2 / 100;

m3 = m1 + m2;

m3 > 59 ? m3=m3%60, h3=1 : h3=0;

h3 = h1 + h2 + h3;

h3 > 23 ? h3=h3%24, d=1 : d=0; /* If more than 23 hours */

printf("\nThe time is %d-%d-%d",d,h3,m3);
```

Comment: +1 for detecting the 24h overflow. However the last step of creating the function's result is missing ...

Answer (score 1):

First convert the time to a common domain(sec/millisec...). Then add and make the result to the required format.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the hours together. 13 + 0.
- Get the minutes of each time by subtracting the time with the time/100*100. Note that integer arithmetic in C truncates. Example:

> m = time - (time/100*100)
>
> m = 1345 - (1345/100*100)
>
> m = 1345 - (13*100)
>
> m = 1345 - 1300
>
> m = 45

- Add the minutes together. 45 + 30 = 75.
- Add "the minute sum/60" hours to the result. I.e. 75/60 = 1.
- Then add "the minute sum modulo 60" minutes to the same result. I.e. 75%60 = 15.

Comment: "*... Get the minutes of each time by dividing them by 100 ...*": Err ...?

Comment: @alk That was quite confusing, was it not? Since this is so trivial, I unfortunately left out all the details without thinking. Answer updated with a formula and an example.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
int add2Hours(int _time1,int _time2)
{
    int minutes = (_time1%100 + _time2%100)
    int time = (((minutes/60)+(_time1/100 + _time2/100))%24)*100 + minutes%60;
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Thankss....i used int hour = _time1 / 100 + _time2 / 100;
               int min = _time1 % 100 + _time2 % 100;

               hour += min / 60;
               min = min % 60;


               hour = hour % 24;

               return hour * 100 + min;*/